# Is the word "AS" in the mysql FROM clause optional?

Tags: mysql, syntax

I stumbled across an interesting (to me) query, and I'm not really sure what it does.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT P.* FROM table P WHERE P.status = ...
```

The question is in regard to the `P` specifically `FROM table P`. I know in the `FROM` clause you can use an `AS` clause, but this particular query doesn't. Is the word `AS` optional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definining aliases isn't always optional, but when you do define an alias the keyword `AS` is always optional.

```
table_factor:
    tbl_name [PARTITION (partition_names)] 
        [[AS] alias] [index_hint_list]
  | table_subquery [AS] alias
  | ( table_references )
  | { OJ table_reference LEFT OUTER JOIN table_reference
        ON conditional_expr }
```

Source: [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)

The `AS` keyword is also optional when defining column aliases:

> The AS keyword is optional when aliasing a select_expr with an identifier

Source: [SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)

Answer (score 1):

In this situation it is not required, but there are other situations, such as joining derived tables, where it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Historically the support was a little mixed but it's now a standard that everyone supports and is essential for name-conflict resolution (multiple tables being selected from with same named field[s]).  It's also really great for giving an alias to compound/calculated/virtual fields!

At the end of the day it's "required" if it would otherwise be unambiguous.

Comment: It looks like you were referring to the entire `AS P` being optional, but the question what only about the `AS`.